# c# change color for a picture, but only changed half.by gdi+

Tags: c#, asp.net, gdi+

i have a picture is divided into four parts.i want change color by RGB.but only changed half.
1.change failed when width of the picture less than 256.
2.my small picture maximum not more than 256.
3.Every picture of 256*256 is normal.
4.problem value:r=0,g=0,b=52.

```
 private void Adjust(Bitmap pBitmap, params int[] pValues)
    {
        BitmapData pBitmapData = pBitmap.LockBits(
            new Rectangle(0, 0, pBitmap.Width, pBitmap.Height),
            ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
            PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

        byte[] pData = new byte[pBitmapData.Stride * pBitmap.Height];
        Marshal.Copy(pBitmapData.Scan0, pData, 0, pData.Length);
        pBitmap.UnlockBits(pBitmapData);

        int iOffset = pBitmapData.Stride - pBitmapData.Width * 3;
        int iIndex = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < pBitmapData.Height; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < pBitmapData.Width; j++)
            {
                for (int k = iIndex; k < iIndex + 3; k++)
                {
                    pData[k] = Adjust(pData[k], k);
                }
                iIndex += 3;
            }
            iIndex += iOffset;
        }

        Marshal.Copy(pData, 0, pBitmapData.Scan0, pData.Length);
        //pBitmap.UnlockBits(pBitmapData);
    }


protected  byte Adjust(byte iValue, int iIndex)
        {
            int nColour = 0;

            switch (iIndex % 3)
            {
                case 0:
                    nColour = (int)iValue + m_iBlue;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    nColour = (int)iValue + m_iGreen;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    nColour = (int)iValue + m_iRed;
                    break;
            }


            return nColour;
        }
```

The original picture without using the problem parameters:

[image]

The original image using the problem parameters changed color:

[image]

Comment: I'm slightly concerned by the tagging here - GDI+ has never been officially supported in the asp.net context.

Comment: Adding the stride difference messes it up I think. Your k%3 won't be in the order 0,1,2 anymore after the first line, if iOffset isn't a multiple of 3.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem, as I mentioned in my comment, is that the stride has the potential to mess up the %3 part, so you should pass which colour component you're reading as separate number, and not the full offset. The function doesn't need or use that offset anyway.

On a related note, the simplest way to iterate over an image by byte in my opinion is just by looping over X and Y, and just calculating the true offset inside the loop.

```
for (Int32 y = 0; y < pBitmapData.Height; y++)
{
    for (Int32 x = 0; x < pBitmapData.Width; x++)
    {
        Int32 offset = y * pBitmapData.Stride + x * 3
        for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
        {
            Int32 colOffset = offset + k;
            pData[colOffset] = Adjust(pData[colOffset], k);
        }
    }
}
```

This way, you can just do a case switch on the actual k value as 0/1/2, and not the (offset+k)%3, which has no guarantees to be correct after the first line, since the stride usually rounds lines to a multiple of *four* bytes.

And finally... do boundary checking. You are editing *bytes* and those only go from 0 to 255.

```
protected Byte Adjust(Byte value, Int32 colourComponent)
{
    Int32 newColour = 0;
    switch (colourComponent)
    {
        case 0:
            newColour = value + m_iBlue;
            break;
        case 1:
            newColour = value + m_iGreen;
            break;
        case 2:
            newColour = value + m_iRed;
            break;
    }
    return (Byte)Math.Max(Math.Min(nColour, 255), 0);
}
```

Comment: Although your solution is not available, I have solved it with emgucv.thanks

Comment: Available? Huh?